# Printing the length of shortest way in maze

Tags: java

I'm trying to make Java program finding the shortest way in maze and printing the length of the way.

. is a way and 'x' is obstacle.

If I inputs

```
....xxx.
x.x....x
xxx.....
x......x
...xxxxx
........
xxx.....
xx......
```

the output is infinite:

```
0, 0
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
...
```

and java.lang.StackOverflowError occurs.

The right output must be

```
0, 0
0, 1
1, 1
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
1, 3
2, 3
3, 3
3, 4
3, 5
3, 6
3, 5
3, 4
3, 3
3. 2
4, 2
5, 2
5, 3
6, 3
7, 3
7, 4
7, 5
7, 6
7, 7
16
```

How can I modify my code and get a right answer?
Or what algorithm should I use to make a new code?
I'm so confused..

I tried many times but I can not get the right answer T_T
Plz help me

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShortestMazeWay
{
    static int count=0;
    static int[] result = new int[10000]; // save the move direction
    static int[][] find = new int[8][8];
    static int[][] maze = new int[8][8]; //  0 = can go, 1 = can not go

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            String str = sc.nextLine();

            for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            {
                if(str.charAt(j)=='.')
                    maze[i][j]=0;
                else
                    maze[i][j]=1;
            }
        }

        find(0, 0); // start from (0, 0)
    }

    static void find(int i, int j)
    {
        find[i][j] = 1; // 0 = can go, 1 = can not go
        System.out.println(i+", "+j); // to check the way

        if(i==7 && j==7) // the end point is (7, 7)
            System.out.println(count);

        else
        {
            count++;

            if(i+1<8 && maze[i+1][j]!=1 && find[i+1][j]==0) // ↓ 
            {
                result[count] = 1;
                find[i][j] = 0;
                find(i+1, j);
            }

            else if(j+1<8 && maze[i][j+1]!=1 && find[i][j+1]==0) // →
            {
                result[count] = 2;
                find[i][j] = 0;
                find(i, j+1);
            }

            else if(i-1>=0 && maze[i-1][j]!=1 && find[i-1][j]==0) // ↑
            {
                if(result[count-1]==2) // if moved ↓ in previous step,
                    count--; // go back to previous position
                else
                    result[count] = 3;

                find[i][j] = 0;
                find(i-1, j);
            }

            else if(j-1>=0 && maze[i][j-1]!=1 && find[i][j-1]==0) // ←
            {
                if(result[count-1]==1) // if moved → in previous step,
                    count--; // go back to previous position
                else
                    result[count] = 4;

                find[i][j] = 0;
                find(i, j-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When walking on the `.`'s, you need to make sure you don't step on a `.` that you already stepped on.

One way to do that, is to leave a breadcrumb, e.g. change the `.` to a `*`, and remember to change it back to a '.' when you backtrack.

*Example:* Direction order is `up`,`right`,`down`,`left`:

```
*...xxx. 1  **..xxx. 2  ***.xxx. 3  ****xxx. 4  ****xxx. 5  ****xxx. 6
x.x....x    x.x....x    x.x....x    x.x....x    x.x*...x    x.x**..x
xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....
x......x    x......x    x......x    x......x    x......x    x......x
...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx
........    ........    ........    ........    ........    ........
xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....
xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......

****xxx. 7  ****xxx. 8  ****xxx. 9  ****xxx. 10 ****xxx. 11 ****xxx. 12
x.x***.x    x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x
xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx...*.    xxx...**    xxx...*.    xxx...*.
x......x    x......x    x......x    x......x    x.....*x    x....**x
...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx
........    ........    ........    ........    ........    ........
xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....
xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......

****xxx. 13 ****xxx. 14 ****xxx. 15 ****xxx. 16 ****xxx. 17 ****xxx. 18
x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x    x.x****x
xxx..**.    xxx.***.    xxx.***.    xxx.***.    xxx****.    xxx.***.
x....**x    x....**x    x...***x    x..****x    x..****x    x.*****x
...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx    ...xxxxx
........    ........    ........    ........    ........    ........
xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....    xxx.....
xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......    xx......
```

Notice how it backtracked between step 10 and 11, and again between step 17 and 18.

**Remember:** The first time you get to the end is not necessarily the shortest route. You must try all combinations for all steps, and remember the shortest path found, not just the first path found.

With the direction order used above, here are some examples of complete routes:

```
First       Shortest    Shortest    Last        Longest
****xxx.    ****xxx.    ****xxx.    ****xxx.    ****xxx.
x.x****x    x.x*...x    x.x*...x    x.x*...x    x.x****x
xxx.***.    xxx*....    xxx*....    xxx*....    xxx.***.
x.*****x    x.**...x    x.**...x    x***...x    x.*****x
..*xxxxx    ..*xxxxx    ..*xxxxx    **.xxxxx    ***xxxxx
..******    ..******    ..***...    ****....    ********
xxx....*    xxx....*    xxx.***.    xxx*....    xxx*****
xx.....*    xx.....*    xx....**    xx.*****    xx.*****
```

So, because you have to remember the full route taken every time you get to the end, a stack implementation is better than the recursive implementation currently used.

**UPDATE: OPTIMIZATION**

Had a new thought about a way to solve the problem without backtracking, which means it should be faster.

Replace the breadcrumbs with a step number, i.e. the (fewest) number of steps to get to that position.

Initialize `maze` with `-1` for blocked (`x`) and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for open (`.`), then do this:

```java
walk(maze, 0, 0, 1);
```

```java
private static void walk(int[][] maze, int y, int x, int step) {
    if (y >= 0 && y < 8 && x >= 0 && x < 8 && maze[y][x] > step) {
        maze[y][x] = step;
        walk(maze, y - 1, x, step + 1);
        walk(maze, y + 1, x, step + 1);
        walk(maze, y, x + 1, step + 1);
        walk(maze, y, x - 1, step + 1);
    }
}
```

The result is a maze like this:

```
 1   2   3   4  XX  XX  XX  .. <-- Unreachable
XX   3  XX   5   6   7   8  XX
XX  XX  XX   6   7   8   9  10
XX   9   8   7   8   9  10  XX
11  10   9  XX  XX  XX  XX  XX
12  11  10  11  12  13  14  15
XX  XX  XX  12  13  14  15  16
XX  XX  14  13  14  15  16  17
```

Now you can find the shortest path by tracing from the end (`17`), going to a lower number, until you're back at the start (`1`).

Comment: Wow... I really didn't think about his algorithm.. THANK YOU!! I solved this. So happy!